# The same old story: OnItemClickListener just not working

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

My `OnItemClickListener` not working for my `ListView`

I set it just like this:

```
ChatAdapter ca = new ChatAdapter(this, chatProfileList);
chatListView.setAdapter(ca);
chatListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(ChatAct.this, "Yay its clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Error: Nothing happens when i click on list items, its not triggering at all.

Facts:

- My Adapter contains data because i can see the list items.
- My list items does not have buttons, radio buttons, checkboxes, or any "clickable" view
- I do got OnItemClickListener on my ListView i can print it.
- I have read ALL the posts in stackoveflow about this problem, and none of them helped.

Tried:

- Tried to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to my root of the list_item.xml
- Tried to add `android:focusable="false"` to all of the elements in my list_item.xml
- Tried to add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to my TextViews in my list_item.xml
- Tried to add `android:clickable="false"` to my TextViews in my list_item.xml
- I tried some mixed varieties like: **focusabileInTouchMode, clikable, and focusable** all set to false

I cannot add reputation reward YET, but the first working solution will be awarded with 100 rep.

Please help, Android yet again so random.

**E D I T:**

My adapter's got nothing(?) to steal focus

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public List<ChatUnit> adapterData = new ArrayList<ChatUnit>();
LayoutInflater inflater;

Activity act;

public ChatAdapter(Activity act, List<ChatUnit> adapterData) {

    this.act = act;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(act);
    this.adapterData = adapterData;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

     ChatListView chatListItemView = (ChatListView) convertView;

    if (chatListItemView == null) {

        chatListItemView = new ChatListView(act);
        chatListItemView.initView(this.act);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.nameTv = (TextView) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_name_tv);
        viewHolder.iconIv = (ImageView) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_profile_iv);
        viewHolder.gameRequestsTv = (TextView) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_naptar_tv);
        viewHolder.newMessagesTv = (TextView) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_bubi_tv);
        viewHolder.backgroundViewGroup = (ViewGroup) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_item_backgroun);
        viewHolder.chatSchedImg = (ImageView) chatListItemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_sched_img);

        chatListItemView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) chatListItemView.getTag();
    }

    final ChatUnit chatUnit = adapterData.get(position);

    try {
        if (chatUnit != null) {

            viewHolder.nameTv.setText(chatUnit.name);
            viewHolder.gameRequestsTv.setText(chatUnit.gameRequest);
            viewHolder.newMessagesTv.setText(chatUnit.newMessage);
            Picasso.with(this.act).load(chatUnit.pictureUrl).into(viewHolder.iconIv);

            // Set!!!!
            chatListItemView.setData(chatUnit);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return chatListItemView;
}

class ViewHolder {

    // ..
    public ViewGroup backgroundViewGroup;
    public TextView nameTv;
    public ImageView iconIv;

    public TextView gameRequestsTv;
    public TextView newMessagesTv;

    public ImageView chatSchedImg;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (adapterData != null) {
        return adapterData.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public List<ChatUnit> getAdapterData() {
    return adapterData;
}

}
```

My list_item_view.xml:

Does not contains any view that requests focus or have any clickable thing.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chat_profile_iv"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/male1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <hu.illion.sporttech.views.other.SportTechTextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_name_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Ez egy név itt"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat_online_iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/online" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_online_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Online"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#68ff5d" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_bubi_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:src="@drawable/chatke" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_naptar_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat_sched_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/naptarka" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**E D I T 2:**

I removed my elements one by one just as some of you adviced, and now i ended up with a single linear layout. Still not working.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_list_item_backgroun"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#123"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
```

Comment: I've found that sometimes my Toasts don't work either. Try a `Log.d(TAG, LOG);` in the `onClick`

Comment: list_item.xml source and getView()/bindView()/other "get view" customization of adapter (i think that problem is not with "clickable"  view but "stealing focus" - view maybe EditText or setting up on click listener in getView ...) ... now question is unanswerable (it works form me :P ) and off-topic(This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.)

Comment: Try setting different list item layout. If it works try removing the elements until you find one that is blocking.

Comment: What kind of Adapter do you use ? Can you give some code?

Answer (score 1):

if one of the elements in the inflated views in the list is receiving a touch event (`onClick`, `onKeyDown` etc.) it'll be consumed before it gets to the list items and therefore the listener will not be called